# How to create a string from elements in tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is there a more succinct way to do this?

```
MyList = [(1,2,3),(6,6,7)] # example
msg = "";
for (a,b,c) in MyList:
   msg += str(b)
```

Comment: what is expected input & output?

Comment: what is your MyList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `join`.

```
str_msg = "".join([str(b) for (a,b,c) in MyList])
```

Where the starting quotes contain any delimiter you might want to use between elements and where `MyList` is some collection of string items.

Comment: You get a problem if `b` is not a string.

Comment: I guess you do, in which case, cast b to a string with `str(b)` within that list comprehension. (edited accordingly, thanks)